# How would you define the following optimization problem?

Tags: optimization

**Axiom: Desires drive people and each person desires to continuously experience minimum injustice and maximum justice with respect to everything.**

Given the above axiom, how would I define the optimization problem so that it would account each level of government (management), starting from local and going all the way to the UN, and all possible issues each person would possibly experience either injustice or justice towards.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question. You just can't be serious.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If each person is an `x_i`, then that person is experiencing either justice or injustice every millisecond. We want them to experience minimum possible injustice and maximum possible justice every millisecond. However, we aggregate at each level of management.